# Blogger comments have disappeared

Tags: blogger

I use standart template "Awesome incorporation" on my blog: (gek0n.blogspot.com)
I changed this template to make my blog more readable and comments are gone.
Then i create new blog (Testing), install same template and examine the code: i didn't delete any code related to comments.

After this i recognized that "post.allowComments" variable and other bool-variable, related to comments, are set to 'False'. I tried to switch every combination in options, but nothing happened. Not a one option doesn't change values of variables.

How i can fix this? Maybe there is some way to change variables values? Or any type of option that i don't know?

Comment: Read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution!
Comments options are in every post and exactly this options turn "allowComments" variable in 'True'.

But not a one forums or users or sites couldn't help me!

P.S.
I'm not native English speaker and make questions is hard to me. Sorry for mistakes.